# Problema con WebStorn no abre en Linux

Tags: html, css, linux

Instale Webstorn y al abir la primera vez todo bien pero cuando intente abrirlo por segunda vez no abre nada, Nose a que se deba eso alguna ayuda.?

Intento abrirlo con la terminal ejcutando el comando webstorn pero me da este error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/webstorm", line 136, in 
    start_new_instance(ide_args)
  File "/usr/local/bin/webstorm", line 131, in start_new_instance
    os.execv(RUN_PATH, [bin_file] + args)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

La distro que estoy usando es KaliLinux.

Comment: el ejecutable lo agregaste al  path??

Answer (score 0):

Estas intentando abrir de nuevo el programa que ya esta en ejecución. es probable que tenga instancias en segundo plano a pesar que lo cierres, lo que te aconsejería fuera matar totalmente el proceso mediante el `PID`.

Primero buscas el proceso para encontrar el número del PID

```
ps -f | grep -i webstorm
```

En el PID lo cambias por el número de proceso del programa webstorm

```
kill -9 PID
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Ya lo solucione creo que la carpeta de instalacion no se borraba jejje y yo la borre simplemente lo volvi a instlar y listo.